# In a C++ command-line application, how should I catch exceptions at the top-level?

Tags: c++, exception

I am writing a command-line application in C++. If an unhandled exception occurs, I don't want the app to crash badly, but to clean up as well as possible and print an error message.

How should I catch exceptions at the top-level in order to avoid the program crashing? Should I catch `std::exception`, `...` or something else?

Comment: You should catch whatever exceptions your application will throw. Since you are the one who will be writing the application, only you -- and noone else on stackoverflow.com -- could possibly know which exceptions your future application could possibly throw.

Comment: Do note that it is implementation defined if stack unwinding occurs when the exception propagates up.  If you wait until `main` you may not be able to clean up anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver - if the exception is **caught** in `main` everything gets cleaned up appropriately. It's only when it propagates **out of** `main` (i.e., `terminate` gets called because there is no handler for the exception) that it may or may not destroy auto objects.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was under the impression that if the exception was raised down the call chain and it propagates back up the call chain looking for a handler that it implementation defined if it unwinds the call stack on its way back up.  Is that not the case?  Will local function objects that were down the call chain be handled correctly?

Comment: @NathanOliver - when an exception is caught, auto variables from further down the call chain have all been destroyed. That's fundamental to RAII.

Comment: @PeteBecker OK.  Great to know.  I guess I was not taught that correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The quality of the cleaning you can do is a function of the exception being thrown.

For example, an exception that you raise yourself (perhaps derived from `std::exception`; let's call it `fooexception`) could well be handled quite elegantly.

So really you want a catch site on these lines

```
try {
    /*whatever*/

} catch (fooexception& fe){
    /*ToDo - handle my exception*/
} catch (std::exception& e){
    /*ToDo - handle this generically*/
} catch (...){
    /*Hum. That's bad. Let's do my best*/
}
```

Extend this at your leisure. Just remember that in a sense, multiple `catch` blocks behave like `if` `else` blocks: always order with the specific exceptions first.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could catch both:

```
int main() {
    try {
        // do stuff
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Caught unknown exception." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should catch both, and possibly more. If you use a more specific exception type somewhere in the call stack, try to catch that as well.

Consider the code:

```
try
{
    process();  
}
catch (const SpecificException& ex)
{
    std::cerr << "SpecificException occured: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (const std::runtime_error& ex)
{
    std::cerr << "std::runtime_error occured: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "Unknown error occured!" << std::endl; // should never happen hopefully
}
```

And remember to always sort by specificness of exceptions - the more specialized/derived first, as the runtime will stop at the first catch block able to process the exception (i.e. first catch block with exception type matching or being a base of).